# Using Pandas Python to create code that puts the tab sheet names of an excel file into a list

Tags: python, excel

I've been stuck with trying to make this code. Using Pandas and Python, I'm trying to make some code that goes through an excel file and adds the names of the excel sheets to a list. (So say that I don't know how many tabs are in an excel file, I want to be able to create a list that is filled with their names, if that makes sense)

my thought process is that for every tab in an excel file, it is indexed into a list (coming from a guy that mostly learned to code in Java, I want it to work similar like an ArrayList, where values are added to the list)

What I currently have so far is:

```
locFile = 'filepath.xlsx'
name = pd.DataFrame()
     for i in range(len(TabList)): 
          TabName = TabList[i]
          name = pd.read_excel(locFile.sheet_name = TabName)
```

But it doesn't seem to work as I'm getting the error

```
 'locFile' object has no attribute 'sheet_name'
```

I think I did something wrong, can I ask for some help?

Comment: `locFile = 'filepath.xlsx'` just defines a string, it doesn't open the file. `name = pd.DataFrame()` is just initialising an empty DataFrame, which doesn't serve any purpose. You haven't shown what `TabList` is, so it's tough to answer this question. Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: `name = pd.read_excel(locFile)` _may_ be valid to read the Excel file. But since `locFile` is just a string in your code, `locFile.sheet_name` doesn't make sense because you're trying to access an attribute (`sheet_name`) of a simple string (it could be a file, a person's name, anything).

Comment: Maybe read [ask] and [mcve], and rewrite the question accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_sheet_names_as_list(excel_file_path):
    import pandas as pd
    pd_xl = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file_path)
    return pd_xl.sheet_names

get_sheet_names_as_list(PATH_TO_YOUR_EXCEL_FILE)
```